# referrer / location - javascript:window["contents"]

Tags: javascript, http, browser

Can anybody explain how the following javascript variables:

```
document.referrer
document.location.href
```

or the http REFERRER header, could come to be 'javascript:window["contents"]' ?

Not only do I not understand how they could be set to a javascript uri - but window.contents isn't a standard DOM attribute in any browser that I know of... (It is window["contents"], not window["content"])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the solution to this..

There are some javascripts in the wild which seem to create iframes using code (something) like this:

```
var contents = '<html>......</html>';
var ifr = document.createElement('iframe');
ifr.contentWindow.open();
ifr.contentWindow.write(contents);
```

some particular combination of this sometimes ends up specifying either the href of the iframe , or the referrer, as  "javascript:window['contents']" - i.e. the javascript variable which temporarily holds the page data.

(still not completely finalized on the details, but that's the basic idea)