# document.location.href got javascript:window["contents"]

Tags: javascript, dom

The return value of `document.location.href` will become `javascript:window["contents"]` sometimes.
 When it will happened? how to avoid it?

I found out
The code is placed in an iframe without src url.

```
<iframe id="google_ads_iframe_/21202031/LTN-000-03-HOME-120X600-DISPLAY_0" name="google_ads_iframe_/21202031/LTN-000-03-HOME-120X600-DISPLAY_0" width="120" height="600" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" src="javascript:&quot;<html><body style='background:transparent'></body></html>&quot;" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;"></iframe>
```

Comment: Can you provide e demo?

Comment: @lucemia Show your demo

Comment: Some other code on your page is causing this to happen. Without that code your question cannot be answered.

Comment: thanks, i will try to provide a demo. because it happened in a javascript ad plugin, so without the `document.location.href` info, I can hardly find a demo either.

Comment: `location` is a property of `window`, not `document`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already have suspected, this indeed has to do with (I)Frames and more specifically, the way some scripts/libraries work with those frames.

It is *a* technique to avoid a `ReferenceError` (in IE) in some cases when loading an external javascript (that is loaded asynchronous) which holds/provides variables/objects that are used in the frame's inline-script-source.

To quote the most relevant part from an article called '[inject content into a new iframe](http://sparecycles.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/inject-content-into-a-new-iframe/)' :

> Instead of using document.open/write/close we use the following
>   approach:
>
> ```
> iframe.contentWindow.contents = content;
> iframe.src = 'javascript:window["contents"]';
> ```
>
> First, we assign the dynamic content to a variable on the iframe’s
>   window object. Then we invoke it via the javascript: scheme. This not
>   only renders the HTML properly, but loads and executes the scripts in
>   the desired order.

This is also in-line with a [similar answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13987659/588079).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For me I have 3 tabs that open with Internet Explorer ... Yahoo, MSN and my email account. Went to "tools" >Internet Options and removed Yahoo, okay and closed. After I verified that I no longer got the java script error tab I reinstalled Yahoo and that solved the problem.